# Unsupervised sequence identification

Tags: feature-extraction, sequence

I am looking for the best method to go from a sequence of events such as

```
time event
1 a
2 b
3 a
4 b
5 c
6 d
7 c
8 d
9 e
```

Where each letter corresponds to a certain event that occurs at a time. I want to reduce the number of events by aggregating frequently occurring events into a new event. A possible solution data set would look like,

```
1 a'
2 a'
3 a'
4 a' 
5 b'
6 b'
7 b'
8 b'
9 e
```

where the clusters are created because they occur in a sequence following each other.

I was looking at the text mining algorithms in R with tm or RNA sequenceing
with edgeR. But I have no experience in this so I was hoping that someone can
shed me some light on a common approach for this type of problems.

Comment: Lots of details and context is missing. It is unclear what those sequences are and what does it mean to transform.
A wild wild guess: you have a set of sequences with corresponding output sequences. RNN can learn such transoframation (similar to machine translation, e.g. from english to french).

Comment: Are you wanting to aggregate events by some common features of their "type" (independent of where they appear in the sequence) e.g. you consider `a'` in your example to cover `a` and `b` because they are similar in some way? Or are you wanting to cluster events by when they occur in the sequence e.g. you are combining `a` and `b` *because* they occur together?

Comment: They occur in sequence. Not because they have any kind of resemblance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ngram`s to get the frequent sequences of you events.

Here a little example

```
 library(tau)
 seq <- "ababcdcde"
 textcnt(seq, method="ngram", n=3L, decreasing=TRUE)

   _   a  ab   b   c  cd   d  _a _ab aba abc  ba bab  bc bcd cdc cde  dc dcd  de de_   e  e_ 
   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Select the *longest* and *most frequent* ngram, here **ab** and **cd**.
You may also trade off the length and frequency to get maximal compression. The **n** parameter limits the length of the ngram.